# Passing id value to external function with popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm stuck trying to pass an id value to another function.

JQuery:

```
$('a.btnPopClass').popover({
            placement: 'right',
            html: true,
    content: 'Are you sure?<br><br><a class="btn btn-danger btn-block" id="click-me">Yes</a>'
}).parent().on('click', '#click-me', function() {
    delete_row(id);
});
```

HTML:

```
<a type="button" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="btnPopClass btn btn-danger btn-block">Remove</a>
```

The button gets an data-id value and i want to pass this value to the delete_row() function. I've been experimenting with 
  $(this).data('id') but i can't visualize how to work my way past the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event that set the id as a `data` attribute.

```
.click(function() {
  $(this).next(".popover").find("a").attr("data-id",$(this).data("id"));
})
```

```js
$('a.btnPopClass').popover({
  placement: 'bottom',
  html: true,
  content: 'Are you sure?<br><br><a class="btn btn-danger btn-block" id="click-me">Yes</a>'
}).click(function() {
  $(this).next(".popover").find("a").attr("data-id",$(this).data("id"));
}).parent().on('click', '#click-me', function() {
  alert($(this).data("id"));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a type="button" data-id="2" class="btnPopClass btn btn-danger btn-block">Remove</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assign an id to your Remove button so you can search for it and get the ID that you already have assigned to it. This will specifically find the RemoveAction button instead of all A links in your page:

```js
$('a.btnPopClass').popover({
            placement: 'right',
            html: true,
    content: 'Are you sure?<br><br><a class="btn btn-danger btn-block" id="click-me">Yes</a>'
}).parent().on('click', '#click-me', function() {
  alert($('#RemoveAction').data('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/css/tether.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a type="button" data-id="50" id="RemoveAction" class="btnPopClass btn btn-danger btn-block">Remove</a>
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/HappyiPhone/2mrsgsow/